# append 0x to hex number in buffer byte with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, hex

I am trying to communicate with an old machine using node.js/electron and RS232C. Basic communication is working but the machine will only accept bytes that are preceded by 0x.

```
var buffer = new Buffer([0x59]);
port.write(buffer);
```

will work and the command will execute, however:

```
var buffer = new Buffer([59]);
port.write(buffer);
```

will freeze the machine.

My problem is I am trying to dynamically create the bytes and the machine keeps freezing. With a port analyzer I can see that 59 is being sent, unfortunately the analyzer displays 59 for both 0x59 and 59.

My code is:

```
var bufferHead = new Buffer([0x06,0x02]);
var bufferHead2 = new Buffer([0x30,0x41,0x46,0x4C]);      
var bufferData = new Buffer([0x4E,0x45,0x57,0x54,0x45,0x58,0x7E,0x31,0x2E,0x54,0x58,0x54,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x30,0x20,0x32,0x30,0x2D,0x31,0x30,0x2D,0x32,0x30,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x37,0x48,0x33,0x30,0x4D,0x0D]);
var bufferFoot = new Buffer([0x03]);      

var bufferNum=0;
var preBuffer = Buffer.concat([bufferHead2, bufferData, bufferFoot]);
for (let x of preBuffer) {
  bufferNum = bufferNum ^ x;
}

var finalBuffer = Buffer.concat([bufferHead, preBuffer, new Buffer([parseInt(bufferNum.toString(16))])]);
port.write(finalBuffer);
```

Now almost all the bytes are hardcoded but finally everything needs to be dynamic.
How can I append the 0x to create a byte identical to the hardcoded one?
There are many posts saying 0x is not needed, but it seems it is in my case unless there is a mistake in my code.

Any help finding a solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

after a day of trying within 10 minutes of posting I figured it out.
my parseInt is missing the 16 radix

```
new Buffer([parseInt(bufferNum.toString(16))])]
```

should be

```
new Buffer([parseInt(bufferNum.toString(16),16)])]
```

Hopefully this or some of the other code will be useful to someone.